# Sabre Create Empty PNR

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to create an empty PNR(with only mandatory fields).
I'm using Soap services from java.
After the CreateSessionRQ I'm invoking TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ to add at least one Person and the ticket type (7TAW) and this call end with success.

Then I invoke OTA_AirBookLLSRQ to create one OPEN segment.

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:OTA_AirBookRQ xmlns:ns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" Version="2.1.0" TimeStamp="2016-03-24T16:04:05.597+01:00">
     <ns:OriginDestinationInformation>
        <ns:FlightSegment Status="OPEN" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="Y">
           <ns:DestinationLocation LocationCode="MXP" />
           <ns:MarketingAirline Code="AZ" />
           <ns:OriginLocation LocationCode="FCO" />
        </ns:FlightSegment>
     </ns:OriginDestinationInformation>
  </ns:OTA_AirBookRQ>
```

The response is:

`<stl:ApplicationResults xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" status="NotProcessed">
   <stl:Error timeStamp="2016-03-24T10:06:08-05:00" type="Validation">
      <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
         <stl:Message>cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'FlightNumber' must appear on element 'ns:FlightSegment'.</stl:Message>
         <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</stl:ShortText>
      </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
   </stl:Error>
</stl:ApplicationResults>`

In the documentation of OTA_AirBookRQ service I read then flightNumber "OPEN can also be passed if the user desires an open space ticket."

I have tried both omitting the tag or by inserting it empty, but the field is always required.

What am I doing wrong?
Is correct the sequence to create the PNR?(After the OTA_AirBookRQ I suppose to call EndTransactionRQ and then CloseSessionRQ)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've found in Sabre samples:

```
<!-- Book an OPEN itinerary. --> 
<OTA_AirBookRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.1.0">
<OriginDestinationInformation>
<FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2012-12-21T12:00" ArrivalDateTime="2012-12-21T17:00" FlightNumber="OPEN" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="Y" Status="DS">
<DestinationLocation LocationCode="LAS"/>
<MarketingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="OPEN"/>
<OperatingAirline Code="AA"/>
<OriginLocation LocationCode="DFW"/>
</FlightSegment>
</OriginDestinationInformation>
</OTA_AirBookRQ>
```

"OPEN" must set in the fligh number field and "DS" in status field

Comment: use rest api its more easier